# Requesting recommendation for an application to detect sound card and its capability

Tags: audio, hardware

Is there an application that can detect the kind of sound card the computer has and list its capabilities like playing 24-bit sound or playing 192khz audio?

Answer (score 1):

PassMark SoundCheck is a Windows based application that allows users to test their PC sound card, speakers and microphone. Verify that your sound card can record and playback sounds at various audio sample rates.   Check the capability of your speakers to reproduce the highest and lowest frequencies (and your capability to hear these frequencies).

Some Other Features
1-  8, 16 and 24bit recording and playback.
2-  Adjustable frame rate for slower PCs.
3-  Source device selection when multiple sound devices are installed
http://www.passmark.com/products/soundcheck.htm